# Собираем строку после опред. знака

Tags: mysqli, php

Подскажите как собрать строку в переменную к пример $url после знака `=`
то есть мне надо, к примеру отсюда http://www.youtube.com/watch?=A5tANTetpRA собрать только `A5tANTetpRA`, то есть что стоит после знака `=`

подсказали сделать на parse_url но там только после знака `?` собрать можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

preg_match и регулярные выражения Вам в помощь.

```
$введите код здесьurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?=A5tANTetpRA';
preg_match('!^http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?=(\w*)$!',$url,$line);

echo $line['1'];
```

результат A5tANTetpRA

Comment: в помощь, но не составить :)

Comment: Всмысле составить? Вам нужно сформировать ссылку или взять из неё часть?

Comment: взять из неё часть 
пример: http://www.youtube.com/watch?=A5tANTetpRA 
брать всегда после знака =

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Мне выдает просто 1, или 0, все точно как у вас скопировано.

Comment: вообщем никто не помог)

Comment: Извиняюсь. Тупанул. прег складывает результат в массив выставленый третьим аргументом. Исправил ответ.